# ZP-OFDM vs. CP-OFDM channel equalization

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, equalization, equalizer

Now, I am working on OFDM equalization, according to what I understood, Adding CP into the OFDM block change the convolution from linear to circular. That circular convolution enables using point-wise equalizer or one tap equalizer such that ZF or MMSE equalizer.

ZP-OFDM is a different scheme, where the CP is replaced by zeros. As I understood, ZP-OFDM should achieve the same performance of CP but under more complex equalization.

So, What means by complex equalization?? Is it time-domain equalization ? Could someone explain for me which equalizer we can adopt with ZP-OFDM in order to achieve similar/near performance of CP-OFDM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you could convert zero padded ofdm into cyclic ofdm at the receiver, and use the same equalization. Though there will be more noise on this scheme.

I had asked a puzzle some time back on this topic:

[Modelling zero padded OFDM as circular convolution between channel and FFT frame](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66525/modelling-zero-padded-ofdm-as-circular-convolution-between-channel-and-fft-frame)

Comment: That's really interesting !! have you checked that idea by simulation? ..   Thank you very much for that comment.  And I still need to know how can we equalize the channel in ZP-OFDM.

Comment: There are techniques you can Google them or find in literature, ZP OFDM is used in marine communications, mostly non linear equalization is required

Comment: Additionally,  I think that is feasible in case if the length of channel $L$ is known.

Comment: Regarding the techniques, I tried googling them, I couldn't find clear way.

Comment: Even to decide the CP in CPOFDM you would need to know the delay spread /channel taps  to decide on the length of CP

Comment: Here you have two equalizer schemes of reduced complexity for zero padded ofdm https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/861158

Comment: Thank you so much